# A question on a periodic function

Tags: functions

Let $f(x)$ be a bounded real function on $\mathbb R$ and for any $x \in \mathbb R$
$$
f(x+\frac{13} {42})+f(x)=f(x+\frac16)+f(x+\frac17) \tag1.
$$

What is the fastest way to compute the period of the function?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $f$ could be constant. It could also have period $1/42$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without any extra assumptions on $f$, you can take this example: Let $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 0 & x \notin \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$$

This function satisfies your equation and is periodic with period $r$ for any rational number $r$. (And has no smallest period.)

Comment: I don't know how to compute the period of a function in generel.

Comment: Paul, no one knows how to compute the period of a function in general. In particular cases, given enough information about the function, there are methods.